# Generate random number in increments of X in Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, function, random, numbers

I'm trying to generate random numbers in increments of X using a generic function in Javascript which returns a random number, my function is:

```js
function getRndInteger(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) ) * 30 + min;
}
```

When used, e.g: `getRndInteger(50, 500)` a random number will be generated, e.g: `253`, however, I'm trying to modify my function to generate a random number between Z and X, but in increments of A, so for instance, `250, 300, 350, 400 ...` etc. I've tried:

```js
function getRndInteger(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) ) * 50 + min;
}

// and...

function getRndInteger(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) * 50 ) + min;
}
```

both of these return numbers beyond my maximum number.

Answer (score 1):

You could divide by the wanted delta and multiply the random value by it to get a wanted gap.

```js
function getRndInteger(min, max, delta) {
    return delta * Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) / delta + min / delta);
}

console.log(...Array.from({ length: 10 }, getRndInteger.bind(null, 50, 500, 50)));
```

Answer (score 0):

As described on the [Mozilla Developer Site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random), use this approach:

```
/**
 * Returns a random number between min (inclusive) and max (exclusive)
 */
function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

/**
 * Returns a random integer between min (inclusive) and max (inclusive).
 * The value is no lower than min (or the next integer greater than min
 * if min isn't an integer) and no greater than max (or the next integer
 * lower than max if max isn't an integer).
 * Using Math.round() will give you a non-uniform distribution!
 */
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

After you have a random number in your range, you can then round it to the desired increment.

```
Math.ceil(number / 100) * 100 // rounds to next 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function getRndInteger(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
var x = 1;
var max = 1000;
for(i=0;i<=5;i++){
  x = getRndInteger(x,max)
  console.log(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to have understand well. This function generate numbers from min and max with a specific step:

```js
function getRndInteger(min, max, step) {
  const range = (max - min) / step;
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * range) * step + min  
}
console.log(getRndInteger(50, 500, 10))
```

is it what you need?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function random(min, max) {
  // get max multiplier 
  let totalSteps = Math.floor(max / min);

  // get a random multiplier between 1 and max multiplier
  let randomStep = Math.floor(Math.random() * totalSteps) + 1;

  // multiply by min and return
  return randomStep * min;
}
```